# Get the complete command line of a process

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I can run `taskmgr`, Display, add column, select "command line", and I will see the complete command line of a process.

For what I check, this command line is quite long, and I can write it out (`CTRL-C` is ineffective). Is there a better way?

Comment: typo, I can write it, not copy it

Comment: For what it's worth: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/25/9928372.aspx

Answer (score 15):

[Sysinternals Process Explorer][1] is a much more powerful process manager.

It has, among other features, the one you're looking for: Right-click a process, click "Properties", and click the "Image" tab on the popup window. It should have a copy-able "Command line" section

If you don't want to install something new, you can use WMIC. To do this, open a command prompt and type

```
WMIC /OUTPUT:C:\Desired_location_here.txt PROCESS get Caption,Commandline,Processid
```

Then, open the text file and the second column should be what you're looking for
[1]: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Answer (score 5):

Double-click a process in [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), it will display the command line in a edit-box. You can also use [WMI](https://web.archive.org/web/20100712112028/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/25/9928372.aspx):

> If you look around in WMI, you’ll find a Win32_Process object, and lo and behold, it has a CommandLine property. Let’s check it out, using the standard WMI application:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
For Each objItem in colItems
     Wscript.Echo objItem.Name
     Wscript.Echo objItem.CommandLine
Next
```