# Give each NodeJs Process a name in Windows TaskList

Tags: windows, task-manager, node.js

I have many nodejs software running.  (Each node.exe is other script)
I want to understand the memory, cpu of each of them.
But all looks similar at Windows TaskList

**An image of Windows Task List:**

[image: An image of Windows Task List]

I've reviewed [How do I find out command line arguments of a running program?](https://superuser.com/questions/415360/how-do-i-find-out-command-line-arguments-of-a-running-program) but that question and its answers deal with finding the arguments passed to an executable.  I want to see this *in Task Manager*.

Comment: How are you starting your scripts?

Comment: node myapp.js, node myapp2.js, node otherscript.js, and so on...

Comment: See [How do I find out command line arguments of a running program?](http://superuser.com/q/415360) which shows you how to see the arguments (you should be able to see the script name in the arguments.

Comment: It is not duplicate because I want to see in the taskmanagaer... But thankyou it also can helps