# How to get the command line of a running application?

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments

If I've got a program open, for example `notepad this.txt`, how can I get the full command line of this application including the arguments which was used to launch the program?

Ideally, I'd like a way which supports copying, as this command is quite long.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the complete command line of a process](https://superuser.com/questions/403423/get-the-complete-command-line-of-a-process)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this solution:

1. Download Process Explorer from here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653
2. Run the `procexp.exe` file.
3. Locate the name of the process you want the command line of.
4. Right click → Properties
5. The command line is then shown in the "Command line:" field.

Answer (score 1):

Open task manager. Click Processes. Click view, select columns. Choose command line from the list

Comment: I was aware of this in my searching, however this doesn't seem to support copy/pasting. A problem if the command line is 1000+ chars.

Comment: @minerz029 Ahhhh. Yea, that won't do it then